# Setting CF environment variable with multiline value

Tags: bash, cloud-foundry

I want to set a RSA token in environment variable of CF App.

I try to set it with below commands

```
export var1=`cat key.pem`
cf set-env app KEY "$var1"
```

If I console the env variable(`cf env app`), I get the expected output:

```
.
.
User-Provided:
KEY: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.
. multi-line key contents
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, if I run the app, it fails in the authentication.

I also tried applying quotes:

```
cf set-env app KEY "'$var1'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the token issue.
The first approach mentioned in the question worked.